# assignment makes integer from pointer

Tags: c, pointers, int, addition, assignment-operator

I have the famous

> "assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast"

problem. I know what this means but I cannot find a way to solve it.
The below instruction caused the the problem

```
champ->instruction.instruction[i + 1] =
        (champ->pc + (champ->instruction.instruction[i + 1] % IDX_MOD));
```

`champ->instruction.instruction` is an `int *`.

`champ->pc` is an `unsigned char *` which countains the address of an array.

`IDX_MOD` is a define like `#define IDX_MOD 36`.

I can solve the problem by declaring an variable like : `unsigned char *tmp;`

but then I cannot put this variable in my `champ->instruction.instruction`.

Can anyone have an idea ?

Comment: Please edit your question to show some more declarations (e.g. of type of `*champ`, `champ->instruction` etc...)

Comment: Are you trying to access the p-th element of `champ->pc`? Would not then `champ->pc[champ->instruction.instruction[i + 1] % IDX_MOD]` work?

Comment: Explain some more about what you are trying to do. It's pretty plain that you are assigning an `unsigned char *` to an `int` , which is an error, and you seem to understand that, but without knowing what your goal is it's hard to suggest a course of action. Can you show some more context or give an example of what sort of result you expect?

Answer (score 1):

As per your code,

- `champ->instruction.instruction` is an `int *`
- `champ->instruction.instruction[i + 1]` is `int`

and

- `champ->pc` is `unsigned char *`
- `champ->instruction.instruction[i + 1] % IDX_MOD` yields `int` value
- `(champ->pc + (champ->instruction.instruction[i + 1] % IDX_MOD))` yields `unsigned char *`

*Note: [ `pointer` + `integer` yields `pointer`, not `integer`]*

So, basically, you're trying to assign a `unsigned char *` to `int`. Hence the error.

To hold (assign) the value of an `unsigned char *`, you need to have an lvalue of type `unsigned char *`. Maybe you want to change the type of `champ->instruction.instruction` to `unsigned char **`.

---

EDIT:

As mentioned by Mr. **@Eregrith** in the comments, changing `champ->instruction.instruction` to `unsigned char **` will create the need for use of `atoi()` or `strtol()`. You need to take care of that.

Otherwise, there is a possibility that you *may have wanted to dereference* the RHS pointer before assigning the result to LHS. in that case, your expression will look like

```
champ->instruction.instruction[i + 1] =
     * (champ->pc + (champ->instruction.instruction[i + 1] % IDX_MOD));
     ^
     |
//dereference before assigning, will result in a char value, promoted to int.
```

Comment: I don't know if it would work because champ->instruction.instruction needs to store sometimes 4 bytes.

Comment: @DimitriDanilov That is upto you to decide about the design, we can only comment on the code shown here. However, Just FYI, you know that ___usually___ `int *` and `char *` variables take up the same amount of space, right?

Comment: Note that changing `champ->instruction.instruction` to an `unsigned char**` would call to a use of `atoi` or similar when trying to calculate `% IDX_MOD`

Comment: @Eregrith Thanks !! I missed that part. Will address the same in my answer itself. :-)

Comment: @SouravGhosh Thanks very much , I tried to declare instruction with unsigned char ** first but it creats a lots of problem. So tried champ->instruction.instruction[i + 1] =
     * (champ->pc + (champ->instruction.instruction[i + 1] % IDX_MOD)); and it works fine !

Answer (score 0):

The expression

```
(champ->pc + (champ->instruction.instruction[i + 1] % IDX_MOD))
```

has type char*, and trying to cast it into int will cause the compiler to issue a warning, because the C standard doesn't say that ints are the same size as pointers.